# Counting chunk sizes in intermittent numerical sequences

Tags: r, vector, grouping, subset, sequence

My R problem is how to go from a numerical vector (or data frame) like:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,12,13,14,16,20)
```

Check for continuous sequences, retrieve them all, get their length, min and max and return something like this:

```
    num  count
  1   1     5
  2   5     5
  3   7     2
  4   8     2
  5  12     3
  6  14     3
  7  16     1
  8  20     1
```

Where `num` is the minimum and maximum of each segment, and `count` the length of that segment.

Grouping does not work on integers, so what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this:

```
chunkstart <- which(c(TRUE, diff(a) > 1))
chunkend <- c(chunkstart[-1] - 1, length(a))
chunksize <- chunkend - chunkstart + 1
data.frame(num = c(rbind(a[chunkstart], a[chunkend])), count = rep(chunksize, each = 2))
```